# laravel 5.6: Session not works in Chorme but works in Firefox

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

In

> app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php

I have a redirect like this:

```
return redirect($Product->path())->send()->with('warning', $text);
```

And for printing it in view:

```
@if ($message = Session::get('warning')) {{$message}} @endif
```

It always shows on Firefox. but not in Chorme.

in Chomre it shows sometimes.

what's my wrong?

Comment: Its about cookies for sure. After trying to php artisan cache:clear; if problem still exist, please check your browser cache settings. Also look at the chrome extensions. Like adblock, cacher. These plugins may block your cache system. Maybe its about browser time. If its not the online time, session may not be verified. If problem still occurs, delete all cache file manually.

Comment: Browsing normal or incognito?